How do I use keyboard shortcuts starting wtih <C-c> in Vim?
I'm trying to use python-mode with Vim and a lot of the commands are by default bound to things like '<C-c>rm'. What does this mean? Ctrl+c just exits the current mode, so in normal mode it does nothing, and rm just replaces the current letter with 'm'.
I tried issuing various commands as described (e.g. press ctrl+c and then press g) but it doesn't behave as described (e.g. going to definition).

<C-c>rm is indeed Ctrl+c, then rm. You can apparently change the default <C-c> for something else. Anyway, the plugin's issue tracker is a better place for that kind of question.

https://github.com/python-mode/python-mode/issues/823
This is a known issue with pymode and not related to vim.

 is Ctrl + c by default but you can remap it, it is the same thing as  or any other command that you can remap (like  for exemple), it will change it for all of your commands
see :help map-CTRL-C.

Could you highlight the useful lines from :help map-CTRL-C?
